# Is it possible to change the menu border color in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-menu

I want to change the border color of the drop down menu items.

[image: menu when dark theme] white theme: [image]

Using Python 3.7 and tkinter - my GUI app offer both dark and light themes, so I change the background and foreground colors dynamically. I was able to do it for most widgets, but I did not find a way to change the border color for the drop down menu items.

Here's a sample snippet of how the `file_menu` is defined:

```
self.menubar = tk.Menu(self)
self.file_menu = tk.Menu(self.menubar, tearoff=0)
self.file_menu.add_command(label="New", image=self.mnu_16_new, compound = tk.LEFT, command=self.file_new, accelerator="Ctrl+N", underline=0)
self.file_menu.add_command(label="Open", image=self.mnu_16_opn, compound = tk.LEFT, command=self.file_open, accelerator="Ctrl+O", underline=0)
```

and here how I change the menu items colors (`self.all_menubars` is a list of all the menu items including the `file_menu` above)

```
for menu_item in self.all_menubars:
    menu_item.config(background=self.c_bg, foreground=self.c_fg, 
                     activebackground=self.c_sb, activeforeground=self.c_fg, 
                     selectcolor=self.c_fg, disabledforeground=sel_color)
```

while `self.c_fg`, `self.c_sb`, etc. are color variables.

Comment: I suppose you are aware of https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Changing+Widget+Colors? If it isn't listed there,.there likely is no out-of-the-way solution.

Comment: @Markus: There are some more, do: `self.file_menu.config()` to see the whole `config options`

Comment: @stovfl: can you please explain how does `self.file_menu.config()` show all the options? is there a specific IDE you're using which lists them?

Comment: @Michael: Nothing specific needed, simple do `print(<widget ref>.config())`

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that on windows because the menubar isn't made by tkiner but from other third party apps. You would need to use canvas widget